# How can I tell if user has watched 10 seconds or more of YouTube video?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, youtube, youtube-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook's open graph protocol to publish a "Xxxx watched this video" message on the user's timeline (with their permission, of course).

According to [Facebook's best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/video.watches/#bestpractices) for publishing this message, I shouldn't do it until the user has watched at least 10 seconds of the video. But, all my videos are hosted on YouTube. How can I tell if 10 seconds has elapsed?

The only idea I had was to use YouTube's API to subscribe to the event when the video starts playing, then start an internal timer and publish the Facebook message after 10 seconds. But that's some complex stuff-- I'd also have to catch a paused event and kill the timer, and pause the timer during the buffering. It just seems like there are a lot of opportunities in there for things to go wrong. :-) Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do channels->list with mine=true and get [contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory). This will be a playlistId of all watched videos for authenticated user.

Then you can call [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with videoId and playlistId specified to check if that video is watched (not only opened and exited)